# Using the AssetManager class in libgdx

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I am developing a platform game using libgdx.
I just started to use the `AssetManager` class. My game has one class for BaseLevel which all the other levels extend from it. And one class that load all the things for BaseLevel, after the user done with level one he will get to the next level and so on. The player, the coins, and the enemies are using the same textures during all the levels in my game.

So my question is: Do I need to use my load screen in every start of the level and remove all the things when each level in hiding? Or I just need to use all the textures that have been loaded and not remove them at all?

This is how I load all my Atlases and Textures:

```
     //Atlases
     game.manager.load("ui/buttonright.pack", TextureAtlas.class);
     game.manager.load("ui/buttonleft2.pack", TextureAtlas.class);
     game.manager.load("ui/jumpbutton.pack", TextureAtlas.class);
     game.manager.load("ui/nextlevel.pack", TextureAtlas.class);
     game.manager.load("ui/menupack.pack", TextureAtlas.class);
     game.manager.load("ui/pausebutton.pack", TextureAtlas.class);
     game.manager.load("ui/resumepack.pack", TextureAtlas.class);
     game.manager.load("ui/restartpack.pack", TextureAtlas.class);


     //Textures
     game.manager.load("img/background2.png", Texture.class);
     game.manager.load("img/background2up.png", Texture.class);
```

I use these all the textures and atlasses in all the levels, Am I need to remove them from the AssetMenager class when the level completed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. If the assets are shared by the levels you don't need to unload them. If want to unload them you should first load all the assets for the new level and then unload the assets for the old level. AssetManager does reference counting so any asset that was used by both level would stay loaded (only if you load new then unload old, in that order).

I see you have something called `resumepack.pack` and `restartpack.pack`. If either one of these is used to create a reloading type screen when your application comes back from a pause you might want to avoid using AssetManager for them. If you resume/reloading screen only uses traditional managed resources then you can use those resources to show a progress bar or similar as you resume (assuming you used `Texture.setAssetManager(manager);`).

Answer (score 0):

to unload all the textures and atlas just use

```
 game.manager.unload("ui/buttonright.pack");
 game.manager.unload("img/background2up.png");
```

and so on

for more info on AssetManager use this link[AssetManager](https://code.google.com/p/libgdx/wiki/AssetManager)

Comment: Yes,  but my question is if after a each single level I need to unload all the things even if I use them at the next level.

Comment: a better approach in this scenario is that u categories your textures and atlases with images that u need throughout the game and other type which has level specific images. so that u can unload level specific images and reuse those images which are to be used throughout the game

Comment: Thank you for the replay, it help me a lot.